# add more colour shades to tailwind color system

Tags: colors, tailwind-css

is it possible to add more shades to tailwind, currently it has shades from 50 to 950, I would like to add 1000 and 0.
is that possible?

I was expecting that i can use more shades.

I would like to use as much as possible the cure t framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the theme to customize it.

In `tailwind.config.js`, add `theme.extend.colors`

e.g.

```json
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        blue: {
          0: '#123123',
          1000: '#abcabc',
        },
      }
    },
  },
```

[Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#adding-additional-colors)

[Example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/h29xeVYTgt)